# Azure Data Factory web authentication error when writing the data to a sharepoint site

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, http-status-code-403

I've built a data pipeline to transform some data in data bricks and then be stored back to my data lake storage container where then I want to send the data back to a SharePoint site list. The problem is that when I debug the pipeline, I get a code 403 error on copying the data to a rest API which is supposed to be the option to send data back to a website.

I've already authenticated and allowed access from that same SharePoint site to send data to the data lake storage and it works fine.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kW5P.png)

[Pipeline Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvXem.png)

When giving site permissions on the SharePoint user site I wrote the code to be able to read and write that data and connect the app. I still can't send data back to the same SharePoint site after it's been transformed. I'm not sure if I correctly sunked that data right or if I'm following the process correctly but I couldn't find any resources and information on how to send data back to a SharePoint site.

Like I said before, the pipeline process works fine up to that point of sending the data back into the same SharePoint site where I extracted the original dataset.

Here are some snippets of the configurations I did for trying to send the data back:

[Sink Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPelU.png)

Comment: Please review the tags you choose carefully. This question has nothing to do with Azure Pipelines.